# Y a-t-il des émissions françaises qui ne sont pas trop difficiles ?

Tags: ressources, télévision

Je prends AP French Language & Culture et je ne peux pas écouter le français sans difficulté. Les [émissions d'actualité de tv5monde](http://www.tv5monde.com/cms/chaine-francophone/info/p-1909-L-actualite-en-video.htm) sont d'un bon niveau pour moi mais je cherche d'autres émissions de télé comme les cartoons ou sitcoms qui sont plus décontractées, et puis aussi sont gratuites pour regarder ou qui sont sur Netflix ou un autre site web.

Que recommandez-vous ?

Comment: Pour corrigez vos accents : installez *Apache OpenOffice* ou *LibreOffice* sur votre ordinateur, quelque soit son OS, ajoutez http://www.dicollecte.org/home.php?prj=fr (option française) et vous aurez un correcteur orthographique gratuit très pratique.

Comment: Je pense que beaucoup de dessins animés conviendraient. Vous pouvez par exemple regarder **South Park** en VF même si il est américain.

Comment: Dicollecte, c'est quelque app que je peux télécharger sur mon ordinateur ou une site web avec qui je copie mon texte pour corrigez?

Comment: @FarazMasroor Dicollecte s'intègre avec le gestionnaire des extensions d'OpenOffice ou de LibreOffice. Ce sont des progiciels gratuits, compatibles Microsoft et qui peuvent être installés à coté de MS Office. - P.S. : Je lis votre commentaire seulement maintenant car je n'ai pas été averti de sa présence, vous auriez dû mettre mon nom dans votre message, comme je viens de le faire avec le votre dans ce commentaire.

Answer (score 8):

Je peux recommander *[C'est pas sorcier](https://www.youtube.com/user/cestpassorcierftv)*, qui m'a beaucoup aidé lorsque j'apprenais le français. C'est une émission qui cible les lycéens et explique un éventail énorme de sujets (savants, historiques, économiques).

Comment: Très bon conseil car ça permet d'étendre sans doute beaucoup le vocabulaire dans des domaines spécifiques divers et variés, tout en ayant bien le temps d'assimiler la significations des termes.

Answer (score 1):

Les dessins animés Disney (ou autre) sont parfaits je pense :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any particular current titles, but the "genre" of [soap operas in French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:French_television_soap_operas) could be helpful.

My wife learned a lot from watching American soap operas when she first arrived here 36 years ago.  They moved so slowly from one episode to the next (even from one week/month/year to the next!), that the constant, albeit annoying, repetition served the purpose of adding to and reinforcing her vocab and recognizing the context in which it was used.  Be careful of television advertisements, though, because for a while she was convinced that "saralicious" was a real adjective.

I learned a lot of French from "reading" the magazine 'Nous Deux', which was/is? essentially a soap opera in printed form (photo-romain = real photos in gradual sequence with captions, kind of like a Sunday-paper cartoon, but with real photos).

The ridicule that came/comes/will come from admitting to watching soap operas or reading the likes of "Nous Deux" was/can be somewhat countered with "I'm just watching/reading it to improve my French"!

Anyway, my wife is now endorsed to teach not only prek-12 French, BUT ALSO preK-12 ESL here in Virginia, so who knows where watching/reading such genres in YOUR second/third/fourth language will take YOU! (Good luck and Bravo for staying with it through AP, BTW!)