# How to help a friend learn French?

Tags: vocabulaire, apprentissage, travail

My girlfriend is Russian and I'm a French speaker. We live in France, and we only speak English. Now she really needs to learn French more or less "fast" in order to get a job.

Can you please give me some advice to help her? Should I advise her to read French more than speak, or doesn't it matter?

If she decides to take classes, in the context of looking for a job, which kind of classes? Vocabulary or "conjugaison" or everything at the same time?

Comment: Vous pouvez poser vos questions en français :)

Comment: Je ne savais pas, ça aurait été plus simple j'avoue

Comment: Maybe some of the answers to [this question about learning from French TV shows](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12563) might give you some ideas. Having a French-speaking significant other should provide a much greater incentive (love) for your girlfriend to learn your language (and for you to learn hers) than that of finding a job, but you both must resist the temptation to default to English in order to fully benefit from that glorious incentive. Reading & writing skills  go hand-in-hand with oral skills and they can help "scaffold" each other to higher levels of proficiency.

Comment: There are apps for learning languages on smart phones

Comment: Je dirais, il n'y a pas de magie. La pratique est plus importante que n'importe quel livre ou méthode. Ca fait 10 ans que je vis en Scandinavie et la plupart des gens parle Anglais, du coup je ne progresse pas. Lire et regarder la TV aident et j'arrive à comprendre. Cependant parler est difficile parce que je ne pratique pas. Donc mon tips serait que vous vous addressiez à elle en fr. Ca fait bizarre au debut mais si les proches ne participent pas, ca ne fonctionera pas.

Answer (score 1):

I started learning French 2 years ago. From my experience i find that intensity is key to learning languages. It doesn't really matter how you are doing it as long as you are doing something. Don't worry too much and enjoy the grind haha.

But one aspect that cannot be replaced is the oral component because it is about muscle memory as well. You should encourage her to speak frequently as no amount of reading or writing will make a person speak fluently.

Comment: Merci Chen Ee Woon

Answer (score 1):

J'ai une correspondante Philippine depuis un peu plus de deux années.

Elle aime beaucoup la France, et aime parler français. Son objectif à court terme, donc l'année prochaine, c'est de venir étudier l'architecture en France, mais pour cela, il lui faut un niveau B1.

*C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron* est probablement l'une de mes expressions préférées. Il n'y a pas de secret ; plus on pratique, meilleur on est. On est tous capable de ce meilleur, pas forcément à la même vitesse, mais on le peut tous.

La question qu'on peut se poser, puisque j'ai l'impression qu'il n'y a ici que des Français, c'est comment nous mêmes avons appris l'anglais, par exemple ? A mon humble avis les films, séries (qui n'a jamais mis pause après une phrase de Jon Snow pour la répéter de la même façon ?) et surtout la musique, sont les meilleurs professeurs. J'ai appris l'anglais à travers des albums de NAS ou encore de Police, alors je lui fait écouter Orelsan ou bien Jean Ferrat. Pour les films, c'est plus délicat : les films en VF sous titrées en anglais, ou autres... C'est moins commun, mais ça existe !

Et j'essaie toujours de glisser une phrase au milieu de la conversation (en anglais, donc) en Français. Je peux donc lui apprendre une tournure grammaticale et/ou un nouveau mot, et je lui lis souvent la phrase et l'envoie en message vocal sur "Whatsapp".

J'espère avoir aidé !

Comment: Merci pour tous vos conseils @MonsieurTruite